# How can I add an entry to the Word 2010 Navigation Pane?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm writing a book, and I want to have an entry in the Navigation Pane for the primary organizational elements of the book. I'm using styles, of course, so this generally happens automatically, but I'd also like to have an entry in the Navigation Pane for the book's dedication page. I want the entry to say "Dedication", but there will be no text in the book with this word in it. I considered using white text on a white background so it'd be invisible, but I'm concerned that that will lead to problems when the book is published in various digital formats; I don't want searches for the text "dedication" to match anything, nor do I want the word "dedication" to show up if a reader sets the background color to something other than white.

What I'm essentially looking for is a way to bookmark the dedication page and to give the bookmark a name that will show up in the Navigation Pane. Is there a way to achieve this effect?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, hidden text (e.g. a hidden heading) is also hidden in the navigation pane. Annoying.